# Android Micro SD Card Show Wrong Size

Tags: linux, formatting

I have a 32GB Lexas Micro SD card in my Samsung Galaxy S2 i9100. For some reason, the card consistently shows 12gb as the size of the card. It just randomly started doing this about 2 weeks ago.

I have done an on-device format (as it has prompted me once or twice to format), a format with an SD card utility through the SD card group, and a Windows formatting. It still shows 12GB.

Any solutions?

Comment: perhaps your card is damaged and dying... what does it show in windows using card-reader?

Comment: yeah... i don't really see how that could be. it's a solid state piece of hardware that has zero physical damage. it still reads the 12gb, it wouldn't read anything if it was dead. windows and gparted both show 12GB. i haven't plugged it into a card reader yet, i have just plugged it in using my phone and mounting it as a USB device. cannot get anything to see more than 12GB

Comment: Seems like your card is damaged. I also experienced some similar issues with some of my 32gb card. I wasn't even able to copy beyond 8~10 gb on my cards.

Comment: If you never put more than 12GB on the card, it may have been one of those delightful "counterfeit" cards that has been hacked to display a misleading size, and then sold as larger than it is. Actually odd to have as much as 12 - those are often 4 or 8 GB tops. Then again, if you have not put 11+ GB on it, it may still be reporting falsely. If a legit card, the manufacturer should be replacing it for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try format with 
[Hp usb format tool](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_SDrpPD4AxPaEF0NUVRcU5WSmc/edit?pref=2&pli=1)
i had same issue on usb flash drive and format with this tool resolves issue

Comment: why it downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it may be to do with providing a link to a google drive (instead of HP's website) as the `exe` could be malicious. I checked the file and currently, it's fine, although didn't fix my problem.